# Delay Cairo-Dock

Tags: startup, cairo-dock

Running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to delay Cairo-Dock. What should be in the command in "Startup Applications". I tried it with: "sleep 10; cairo-dock" but that doesn't work. What is the proper syntax to use...
FYI I want to delay Cairo-Dock because when it starts immediately it ruins the shutdown options in the top panel (seems to be a known but unsolved bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sh -c "sleep 10; /usr/bin/cairo-dock"
```

:)

Comment: That helped perfectly. And now the "Shutdown"-options in the top panel still work